# A lot of extra padding to the left of toolbar title

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar that exists across fragments. The first fragment has no up navigation, but when I navigate to the second fragment I make the "up" arrow appear (to go back to the first fragment). However, when I go back to the first fragment and the up arrow disappears, there is a ton of padding to the left of the title. (The gif loops, watch for the 'Fragment 1' title to be spaced far from the left)

[image]

I think this has something to do with having `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` set on my toolbar, because if I remove that line the padding disappears:

[image]

I can't figure out the cause of this, if anyone has a solution that may be able to help I would really appreciate it; whether that be finding a different way to animate the toolbar, or how to get rid of the padding.

Here are the things I've tried so far:

- Getting the relative position of the title text before the fragment transition, then doing `toolbarTitle.setLeft(oldLeft)`, but the `oldLeft` value is never set.
- Trying to remove the padding from the toolbar by putting `app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
  app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` in my toolbar definition, but this only removes 16dp of padding.

I don't think it matters, but here is my toolbar code. I populate the actions in each fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

<TextView
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DEFAULT"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: damn, so many questions about it but literally 0 answers. I think raising issue with google may be the only solution here.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a hack, but I couldn't find anything online so this actually works for me:

```
 toolbar.post {
            val childCount = toolbar.childCount
            for (i in 0..childCount) {
                val child = toolbar.getChildAt(i)
                if (child is TextView) {
                    if (toolbar?.navigationIcon == null) {
                        val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(child, "left", toolbar.contentInsetStart)
                        animator.duration = 300
                        animator.start()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically, when there's no icon displayed in the toolbar (After navigating), I use `toolbar.contentnInsetStart` with `ObjectAnimator` to move back the title with an animation back to its original position.

One thing to note, is animator.duration should be the same duration of `animateLayoutChanges`, so if you're using a custom animator where the duration is different, use that instead, cause if you use anything below the title will snap back to the wrong position.